# ComboBox width different from popup width

Tags: wpf, windows-8, wpf-controls, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How to make a `ComboBox` change its width based on content but make the popup list with items to be of constant width?

Comment: If you don't specify a width value for you ComboBox, it should automatically resize on content.

Comment: this is true, but then the item list while scrolling is resizing on content too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I created a new ItemContainerStyle and set the width of items there, and have not specified the width for the ComboBox.